# How to input TensorImage array or a single TensorImage buffer into a tensorflow lite model?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

## info

Converted a simple model from keras which gets **N images an input and outputs M images**. From Android app (java) I'm loading images as bitmaps and converting the bitmaps into TensorImages, which are later joined together into a **TensorImage array**.

#### case 1

Trying to input the TensorImage array to the model using `tflite.run(inputArray, outputArray)` when **inputArray** is `TensorImage inputArray[] = new TensorImage[]{tensorImage1, tensorImage2, tensorImage3}` results in the following DataType error: `DataType error: cannot resolve DataType of org.tensorflow.lite.support.image.TensorImage`, Which I assume has to do with the input buffer limitations.

#### case 2

Trying to input a single TensorImage's buffer using `tflite.run(tensorImage1.getBuffer(), output.getBuffer())` results in an Illegal Argument Exception: `IllegalArgumentException: Both buffer and bitmap data are obsolete.`

#### case 3

Changed the output to a `TensorBuffer` and created a float32 buffer like so: `TensorBuffer result = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 1, 10}, DataType.FLOAT32)` which works incorrectly since the model is applied on a single image (though it provides an output).

## question

So how should images be given as input into a tflite model?